# Specflow reusing When declared in feature file with C# file

Tags: c#, specflow

I have problem reusing a `When` with `Specflow`. The code example is shown below:

```
Scenario: demo
Given ...
When do something

[Binding]
public class Demo{

 [When(@"do something")]
 public void DoSomething(){
  {  }
}

Scenario: demo 2
Given ...
When do something
...

[Binding]
public class Demo2{

 [When(@"do something")]
 public void DoSomething(){
 {  }

}
```

Compilation error: ambiguous step

Is it possible to reuse `[When(@"do something")]`, rather than hacking it by changing it to, e.g.  `[When(@"do something 2")]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [scoped bindings](http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Scoped-Bindings/) to restrict the binding to a particular feature, scenario or tag.

Hence in your example you would have:

```
Scenario: demo
Given ...
When do something

[Binding]
public class Demo{

 [When(@"do something"), Scope(Scenario = "demo")]
 public void DoSomething(){
  {  }
}

Scenario: demo 2
Given ...
When do something
...

[Binding]
public class Demo2{

 [When(@"do something"), Scope(Scenario = "demo 2")]
 public void DoSomething(){
 {  }

}
```

However, as the linked article says, step definitions coupled to features is an [anti-pattern](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Feature-Coupled-Step-Definitions-%28Antipattern%29), as they do not promote re-use.

I'd recommend renaming the "When" statements so that they are less ambiguous, as they'll help both you and anyone who reads your tests who is unfamiliar with the system e.g. instead of "do something" write it as "When I submit my search parameters". If they are in fact doing the same thing, then re-use the same step definition.

Comment: Renaming the "When" statement work. But it describes the same thing between two scenarios. In this case, renaming seems confusing. Plus, more than two scenarios will use the same When statement. Apart from Scoped bindings, is there are ways to reuse "When" in different Classes with [Binging]?

Comment: But that's kind of the point, if your when statement is the same then you are describing the same thing. As @fresh says its an anti-pattern, or a pattern of something bad.

Comment: I agree with @AlSki. You say "Plus, more than two scenarios will use the same When statement", this is usually a good thing as it means you can re-use the same code (i.e. DRY), meaning it will be easier to maintain this "When" statement if it changes over time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, reuse is very easy as `Binding`s are global. It will help if match your bindings to your features, rather than your scenarios, something like this.

```
Feature: My new feature

Scenario: demo1
Given ...
When do something

Scenario: demo 2
Given ...
When do something
...
```

And then in MyNewFeature.Bindings.cs

```
[Binding]
public class MyNewFeature{

 [When(@"do something")]
 public void DoSomething(){
 {  }    
}
```

Have a read of http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Sharing-Data-between-Bindings/ for some ideas when you want to share your bindings across features.

Comment: I need to reuse "When" in different classes with [Binding], not in the same class. Is there a way, apart from Scoped Binding @Fresh suggest? I cannot see it on the link you provide. Any idea?

Comment: Unfortunately no as `[Binding]`s are global, unless limited in scope. Try adjusting your binding class hierarchies.